# mutliple file is not uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net

### I want to upload multiple images in,but it is not selcting multiple images

```
          <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group m-b">
                            <label>Small Image</label>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUp1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" 
         CssClass="form-control" />
                            <small style="color: red;">Image Size Should be 280*282 px</small>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What is happening currently? Any error?

Comment: no error is occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be of an issue of asp control. Check attribute multiple is present after rendering by inspecting the file upload control in dev tools

If not add it explicitly

`<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUp1" runat="server" multiple CssClass="form-control" />`